# Trying to bind multiple value coming from oracle in dotnet side

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oracle, ado.net

I'm trying to bind a `Dataset` at `.Net` side by retrieving the value from database using stored procedure. In the stored procedure, I am using both out `Sys_Refcursor` and out type parameter but getting error.

I have created a stored procedure in which first I am returning value in out and second in `Sys_Refcursor` values are coming in both `Sys_Refcursor` and `out` parameter but not able to collect at `.Net` side in `Dataset`

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GetMultiVal
(v_var_value out varchar2,v_hr_stk_out out Sys_Refcursor,Crs_out out Sys_Refcursor)
is
var_value varchar2(200);
x varchar2   (200);
cursor age_val is 
 SELECT AGE_CD,
 decode(AGE_CD,'04','CNE(RW','05','CS ','4A',NULL,AGE_DESC) AGE_DESC ,
 AGE_SEQ      
 FROM DBPROD.PROD_AGE_MST
 WHERE AGE_SEQ < 15
 AND AGE_CD NOT IN ('6k','09')
 ORDER BY 3; 
BEGIN
open v_hr_stk_out For 
SELECT AGE_CD,
 decode(AGE_CD,'04','CL LINE(oW','05','RS ','4A',NULL,AGE_DESC) AGE_DESC ,
 AGE_SEQ      
 FROM DBPROD.PROD_AGE_MST
 WHERE AGE_SEQ < 15
 AND AGE_CD NOT IN ('6p','05')
 ORDER BY 3;

    FOR i IN age_val LOOP
      SELECT To_Char(Round(NVL(SUM(NVL(WF_OD_WT, 0)), 0), 0)) 
      INTO X
      FROM DBPROD.od_age_fgs_cur
    WHERE WF_DATE BETWEEN sysdate AND  sysdate+1
       AND WF_AGE_CD=i.AGE_CD;
    var_value :=var_value || X||'~';
       END LOOP;
     v_var_value := var_value ; 
OPEN Crs_out For
SELECT Round(NVL(SUM(NVL(WF_OD_WT,0)),0),0) as Crs_out_val
      FROM DBPROD.od_age_fgs_cur
      WHERE WF_DATE BETWEEN sysdate AND sysdate+1
      AND WF_STAGE_CD='05'
      AND NVL(WF_FG_TYPE,1)!=0;
end;
```

dotnet side

```csharp
command.CommandText = "GetMultiVal";
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.Parameters.Add("v_var_value", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
command.Parameters.Add("Crs_out", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(command);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(ds)
```

Expected: Value should be bind in dataset.

Actual: Getting given error while binding

> "{"ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:\nPLS-00306: wrong number or types of
>   arguments in call to 'GETMULTIVAL'\nORA-06550: line 1, column
>   7:\nPL/SQL: Statement ignored"}

Comment: You store procedure has three parameters while the c# has only tow.  The parameter "v_hr_stk_out" is missing

Comment: @jdweng actually v_var_value is written inside v_hr_stk_out  out sys_refcursor and earlier i was trying to read value of  v_var_value   through it  but getting error

Comment: The parameter list has following : (v_var_value out varchar2,v_hr_stk_out out Sys_Refcursor,Crs_out out Sys_Refcursor)  If you leave out v_hr_stk_out the parameters may be out of order.

Comment: @jdweng then how to bind and read v_var_value  and Crs_out_val in dataset and any idea please suggest

Comment: Read all three values into dataset.  Then delete the column you do not need.

Comment: @jdweng tried as you mentioned but still getting error "wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GETMULTIVAL"

Comment: So you are defining three parameters in the order that they are listed in the store procedure parameter list?

Comment: @jdweng yes in that way i am getting "ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small\nORA-06512:" error

Comment: @jdweng it's working only need to add varchar size at dotnet side

Comment: @jdweng but i am not able to get value of v_var_value in dataset how to get that in dataset or how to find it

Comment: DataColumn columnToRemove = ds.Tables[0].Columns["v_var_value"];
            ds.Tables[0].Columns.Remove(columnToRemove);